# How to run a query to find a string in blob files?

Tags: mysql, sql, mediawiki

Mediawiki has a table in the database 'text' which contains the page content. It is saved as a [BLOB] file. 
I would like to run a query to search through all the text on the site to see which pages contain a certain 'string'. 
How do I run a query to search [blob] files?

Comment: If I remember correctly, MediaWiki can compress the content of the `text` table. Are you sure that's not your case?

Comment: It says in the documentation that the column 'old_flags' can contain a gzip file but it is is also a blob file and when I download it I can't see the gzip file. I have a huge amount of content on my wiki I want to search though all the content, I can't download and unzip each page. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Mediawiki markup text is stored in the `old_text` field, which is a *mediumblob* type.  You can query it like any other text-based field.  MySQL will cast your string into binary for the query.  Note that this is a case-sensitive search!

```
select old_id from text where old_text like "%string%";
```

If you need case-insensitivity then you need to apply an appropriate [character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html) with a case-insensitive collation to the column:

```
SELECT old_id from text where CONVERT(old_text USING latin1) like '%STRing%';
```

Be aware that if your table isn't small these queries will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

As per  the [mediawiki documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_architecture_document/text/revision_2#Database_and_text_storage) text table stores only the text for the revision. Hence to access the complete text, all revisions corresponding to a page need to be processed. It is better to use an API call to [mediawiki search engine](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) and process the results than search using SQL query.