# how to return value of a row if data found(fingerprint template verify)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, biometrics

how to return value of a row if data found(fingerprint template verify) 
I'm making a time attendance monitoring system. NOW I can save data to MYSQL and  verify it from mysql, but I don't know how to retrieve it from mysql,
I want to return the value of a row where the FPT is verified. I'm using VB.net.
i do not have any idea for that.
any help will be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to convert the Fpt into blob file and then access that blob file to select the row that you intend to do..

`select row_id from table_name where field_name like %blob_string%`

Comment: can I use to search or query in table using a blob type?

Comment: of course you can.. refer to this>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563838/how-to-run-a-query-to-find-a-string-in-blob-files

Comment: ok, I would like to query like this, select idnumber from user where fpt like %template.bytes%   . template.bytes is the fingerprint template.

Comment: If template.bytes is a part of the blob file that you have created then this query should work fine.