# How does LIKE operation work on BLOB column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I am having multiple values which are encoded to byte arrays and stored in a BLOB column of mysql

```
encode(val1)+encode(val2)+encode(val3)
```

Now, I have to do LIKE operation on the BLOB column with encode(val1).

How to do this operation and how does it work internally?

Comment: Maybe this will help you [how-to-run-a-query-to-find-a-string-in-blob-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563838/how-to-run-a-query-to-find-a-string-in-blob-files)

Comment: the value is already a byte array. creating a string from it and using it in like dint work..